Thermal energy value being bigger than the work doesn't it mean for the specific example being philosophical?
A university physics student wasn't Happy with his physics teachers answer so he came to me, and asked me how it it possible that applied force is lesser than static frictional force is still making the box move, as we know static friction is always higher than kinetic frictional force then how did the box even move at the beginning? I told him, the question is not a practical real world example because if he was pushing it using 40 N then the box must not move but if it was like at the beginning he gave more value of force bit just when the box started moving he went to 40 N constant force then the question holds, because kinetic frictional force is 44.something so of he was constantly applying 40 N from the beginning then yes the box will not move a even infinitesimal value so, i told him it is more like a philosophical example and not a real life example to begin with so that is why it is like that. I am structuralist mathematician. So if i was wrong then please let me know for which reason i might be wrong?
I want to add more contexts which is that, look at the v initial which is .60 m/s so i told him the question is certainly avoiding the concept of static frictional force, because a box having initial speed of .60 means that the force previous to 40 N must have been bigger than static frictional force otherwise you can't say .60 velocity initial too. If you want to be realistic but the question also contradicts this issue by saying the force is being constant from the beginning so it must be a philosophical example rather than a real life example or it is possible the previous was not given by him but was given by some other entity. But still it is a philosophical example because the previous thermal heat can't instantly vanish so yeah i concluded that the example is not a scientific one.


When you push something heavy (like a piece of furniture), you have to push it hard enough at the beginning to overcome static friction and get it moving, but once it's moving you might let up and only push as hard as you need to keep it moving. So I don't think it's an unrealistic example.

Listen you didn't understand the question the question was what that constant force was being meant by the physicists @d_b


how it it possible that applied force is lesser than static frictional
force is still making the box move, as we know static friction is
always higher than kinetic frictional force then how did the box even
move at the beginning?

The box starts to move when the maximum possible static friction force is reached. Up to that point the static friction force matches the applied force for net force of zero and no motion.
When motion starts there is no static friction and friction becomes kinetic. As you apparently already know the coefficient of kinetic friction is generally less than the coefficient of static friction. That means once motion starts the resisting friction force abruptly decreases. You can see that from the friction plot in the following link:
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/frict2.html#kin
If you ever tried pushing a heavy object across the floor you may have noticed that when the object finally breaks free of the floor  its resistance to your pushing it seems to suddenly decrease. That’s because the kinetic friction force is less than the maximum static friction force you needed to overcome in order to get the object moving.
Hope this helps.

Are there any conditions where static frictional force is lesser than kinetic frictional force? @Bob D

@jastyles Not that I'm aware of, but I suppose there can be an exception. For al list of coefficients see: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/friction-coefficients-d_778.html

It is higher always for all known ones in your list. It has to be otherwise the mathematics would break. @BobD

@jastyles when I said exception I meant they might be the same. I see that apparently is the case for some clean and dry PTFE. I don’t think the mathematics would break if kinetic were higher, it just wouldn’t make physical sense. Anyway, why did you ask the question in the first place if you already knew the answer?

The real truth is that the equations are tools which predict the behavior of the system if they are applied properly.  One of our jobs is to correctly apply them, and one of the big pieces of this is filling in the details that can be inferred from the words.  After all, we know the words don't contain the answer (it would be a very poor problem if they did).   They have to contain enough information for you to reason about the situation to get to an answer ,without giving it to you outright.
it is stated that $v_0$ is equal to $0.6\text{m}{s}$.  That is enough to reason that kinetic friction should be used.  No further deduction is required.
It sounds like your student is confused by how physicists use "constant force."  When we use the word "constant," we mean it is constant within the domain of the problem.  The domain is not always $t\in(-\infty, \infty)$.  In fact, a very common wording is to speak to "initial conditions."  The presence of $v_0$ is a dead giveaway that this problem's domain is only from that moment onward (which I would write as $t\ge 0$).  We need say nothing about how constant the force was before $t=0$.  In fact, it may not even be there.  The food shipper might be a younger brother who is less strong, only able to push with $40N$ of force, but just before $t=0$, his big brother shoved it with $1000N$ of force, setting it in motion. Or maybe it was on an air bearing, which reduces friction to nearly 0, and the air bearing just stops applying air at $t=0$.
There's an infinite arrangement of possible pasts that lead to the initial conditions, limited only by one's creativity.  One of the fascinating things about physics is that that infinite arrangement is immaterial.  You can predict what will happen $t\ge 0$ using only the initial conditions provided.
If you're dying to link it to math, model theory is an effective tool to deal with these myriad possibilities.  One can demonstrate that all interpretations satisfying the initial conditions (the model) entail the same behavior $t\ge 0$, including that kinetic friction should be used.  But I find it more effective to just chalk it up to learning the language.  Constant doesn't always mean the same thing as it does in math.
Similar happens in electronics.  We talk of a "DC" power source where the voltage is constant.  However, at some point someone had to flip a switch or connect the power supply to the rest of the circuit, which is a very non-constant thing.  The idea of a "constant voltage" is one where the power supply was turned on sufficiently long ago that how it reached the current state isn't a major driver in the performance of the circuit.  For a national power grid, that might be measured in seconds or more.  For the chips inside a computer, milliseconds is often enough to qualify as "DC"

Thanks for a quite informative answer. Thanks.

can static frictional force be lower than kinetic frictional force?

@jastyles I'm not aware of it ever happening.  The simple $F_{friction}=\mu F_{normal}$ is just an approximation, not a law, but I can't think of any materials where the coefficient of friction for static friction is lower than the kinetic one.  The momentum of the moving object lets it slide over the top of microscopic hills and valleys.
